# Write query in QueryDsl

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I am using spring-data, QueryDsl etc

Say I have two entities,

```
@Entity
Person {
  @Id
  Integer id;
  String name;
  @OneToMany
  List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
Address {
  @Id
  Integer id;
  String city;
}
```

One Person can have many addresses.

I am trying to write query in QueryDSL for following,

**Give me list of persons who's city name starts with 'xyz'.**

What I did so far,

```
class PersonPredicates {
    public static BooleanExpression cityStartsWith(String city) {
      QPerson person = QPerson.person;
      return person.addresses.  // could not get how to create predicate for this
    }
}
```

Thank you for response.

Comment: you need to join the two tables to fetch eagerly. Some thing like this should work   

new JPAQuery<QPerson>(entityManager).from(QPerson.person)
        .leftJoin(QPerson.person.address, QAddress.address)
        .where(QAddress.address.city).startsWith("xyz").fetch();

Comment: Isn't it just `person.addresses.city.startsWith("xyz")`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce addresses is list.

Comment: Wow I haven't worked with QueryDSL for a while then! But then you'd do `person.addresses.any().city.startsWith("xyz")` I think